# Luck Balance Problem solution produces wrong result

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm

**Problem**

Lena is preparing for an important coding competition that is preceded by a number of sequential preliminary contests. Initially, her luck balance is 0. She believes in "saving luck", and wants to check her theory. Each contest is described by two integers, `L[i]` and `T[i]`:

- `L[i]` is the amount of luck associated with a contest. If Lena wins the contest, her luck balance will decrease by `L[i]`; if she loses it, her luck balance will increase by `L[i]`.
- `T[i]` denotes the contest's importance rating. It's equal to `1` if the contest is important, and it's equal to `0` if it's unimportant.

If Lena loses no more than `k` important contests, what is the maximum amount of luck she can have after competing in all the preliminary contests? This value may be negative.

Please find a full description [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/luck-balance)

**My effort**

So here is the code that I wrote for the question. I am adding all the non-important questions and storing the luck value of all the important questions in an array. Have sorted the array. Then took all the minimum luck balance from questions she is allowed to win and subtracted that and added the luck from the rest of the contest she loses.

**Code**

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the luckBalance function below.
nk = input().split()
n = int(nk[0])
k = int(nk[1])

contests = []

maximumLuckBalance = 0

for i in range(n):
    luckcontestRating = input().split()
    luck =  int(luckcontestRating[0])
    contestRating = int(luckcontestRating[1])
    #print("Contest[",i+1, "]:" + "luck: ", luck, "Contest Imp: ", contestRating)
    if contestRating == 0:
        maximumLuckBalance += luck
    else:
        contests.append(luck)
contests.sort()
#print(contests)
winAllowed = len(contests) - k
#print(winAllowed)
winningLucksum = sum(contests[:winAllowed])
#print(winningLucksum)
loosingLucksum = sum(contests[winAllowed:])
maximumLuckBalance = maximumLuckBalance - winningLucksum + loosingLucksum
print(maximumLuckBalance)
```

**Question**

However, this code fails for one of the test cases (please see the input below). **What's wrong with my solution?**

**Input**

```
97 58
105 0
103 0
106 1
106 1
103 0
103 1
105 1
106 1
105 0
104 0
103 0
102 0
104 0
105 0
104 0
102 1
104 0
106 1
104 1
101 1
105 0
103 0
104 0
106 0
102 1
103 0
102 0
103 1
106 0
104 1
101 1
101 1
106 0
103 1
103 0
104 1
101 0
105 1
105 0
104 1
105 0
106 0
104 0
105 0
101 1
106 1
105 0
103 0
104 1
101 1
106 1
104 0
106 1
105 0
103 1
101 0
103 0
101 0
105 1
104 1
104 1
105 1
105 1
103 0
101 0
104 1
106 1
105 1
105 0
106 1
104 1
105 1
103 1
102 1
106 0
101 0
105 1
104 1
103 1
106 1
101 0
106 1
103 0
106 1
102 1
103 0
101 1
102 1
101 1
104 0
106 0
102 0
104 0
105 0
105 0
102 1
103 1
```

**Expected Output**

```
10069
```

Comment: @Armali it's too big but I reproduced this issue with a small test case in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you assume `k` is always less or equal than the number of rated contests - `len(contests)`.

For instance, let's consider the following input:

```
4 3

1 0 

2 0

3 1

4 1
```

Correct output must be:

```
10
```

But your code will yield:

```
4
```

Because, `winningLucksum = sum(contests[:-1]) = 3` and `losingLucksum = sum(contests[-1:]) = 4` and so `maximumLuckBalance = 3 - 3 + 4 = 4`.

Hence, make sure that `winAllowed` never gets negative by replacing

```
winAllowed = len(contests) - k
```

With a line:

```
winAllowed = max(len(contests) - k, 0)
```

Then, your solution will pass all the tests.